# Does stress cause premature achromotrichia (hair greying)?

Tags: hairloss, stress, achromotrichia, hair-color

I have read contradictory claims on whether stress causes premature achromotrichia.

[DailyMail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-2997084/No-stress-DOESN-T-turn-hair-grey-men-s-beards-really-ginger-Expert-reveals-really-affects-hair-colour.html) (no):

> There is no evidence to link the onset of greying to stress, diet or lifestyle.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_hair_color#Stress) (maybe):

> There is some evidence for chronic stress causing premature achromotrichia, but no definite link has been established. It is known that the stress hormone cortisol accumulates in human hair over time, but whether this has any effect on hair color has not yet been resolved.

Is there any scientific study confirming or infirming the claim?